# Length of $\mathbb{Z}_p$-modules for quaternion algebras

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quaternion-algebras

Consider $G$ the group of units of a division quaternion algebra $D$ over a number field $F$, say $\mathbb{Q}$ for simplicity. Consider a non-central element $x \in G(\mathbb{Z}_p)$: hence, it is regular, semisimple and elliptic.

(1) What can be said about the Weyl discrimiant $|D(x)|_p$?

I know for instance that $|D(x)|_p$ is $p^{-2l}$ where $l$ is the length of the $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module $\mathcal{O}_E/R$ where $E = \mathbb{Q}[X]/P_x$ and $R = \mathbb{Z}[X]/P_x$ (this is a result of Yun). So the question can be reformulated as

(2) Do we know the length $l$ in function of $x$? That is, is there a known bound or an explicit value in function of the element $x$?

Even examples of explicit computations could help.

Comment: What is the Weyl discriminant?  (I don't understand the notation $D(x)$---D is the division algebra, right?)

Comment: @Kimball It is the Weyl discriminant, sorry for the imprecision (usually I read $|D^G(x)|$)